# OpenCV 2.3.1 make highgui errors

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, makefile, highgui

I am attempting to build OpenCV 2.3.1 on a 64 bit OSX Mountain Lion machine and can't get past a particular set of "use of undeclared identifier" make errors. I have attempted to build both the taz.gz file and source from Git with the same errors.

Has anyone successfully built 2.3.1 on a OSX Mountain Lion machine? If so, how did you get past the following errors:

> opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:486:5: error: 
>   use of undeclared identifier 'av_open_input_file' av_open_input_file(&ic, filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
>
> opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:494:5: error: 
>   use of undeclared identifier 'avcodec_thread_init'avcodec_thread_init(enc, get_number_of_cpus());
>
> opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:524:15: error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'av_open_input_file'
>       int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
>
> opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:541:9: error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'avcodec_thread_init'
>           avcodec_thread_init(enc, get_number_of_cpus());

As of now I see a couple of options. I could switch to Ubuntu which appears to have an easier build process or I could fix the highgui code.

If you have previous experience building this version I would appreciate the help.